# Get property value with Expression without knowing target type at compile time

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I'm trying to create an expression lambda to pass an object, and then get the value for named property return. However the type is only known at runtime.

I started with the following method to handle types known at compile time:

```
private static Func<T, object> CreateExpression(string propertyName)
{
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var expr = Expression.Property(arg, propertyName);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(expr, arg).Compile();
}
```

Which worked perfect. However, i need to change it to handle types only known at runtime.

I should be able to call the delegate like this:

```
public object GetPropertyValue(object obj)
{
    var propertyDelegate = GetDelegate(typeof(obj));        
    var propertyValue = propertyDelegate (obj);
    return propertyValue;
}

private Func<object, object> GetDelegate(Type type)
{
    // Lookup delegate in dictionary, or create if not existing
    return CreateDelegate("MyProperty", type);
}
```

I tried changing the CreateDelegate from before, but it will not work with `Func<object, object>`:

```
Func<object,object> CreateDelegate(string propertyName, Type targetType)
{
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(type);
    var body = Expression.Property(arg, name);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object,object>>(body, arg); //ArgumentException
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

It will not accept the Expresion.Parameter, since it is of type 'targetType', and not of type 'object'.

Do i need a Expression.Convert or something?

NOTE: The delegate will be called many times (Filtering method), so it need to be compiled, to ensure performance.

**EDIT: Solution (provided by Marc Gravell)**

the variable 'body' should be changed to the following:

```
var body = Expression.Convert(
             Expression.Property(
               Expression.Convert(arg, type), 
               name), 
             typeof(object));
```

Inner `Convert` converts input parameter to object, and the outer `Convert` converts the return value.

Comment: there is a non-generic version of `Expression.Lambda`, you probably need to look into that

Comment: @Rhumborl that would gain very little; you want a `Func<object,object>` for performance; a `Delegate` with `DynamicInvoke` is very slow.

Comment: I thought about that, but i'm only able to invoke the delegate with DynamicInvoke, which is quite slow. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
var expr = Expression.Property(Expression.Convert(arg, type), propertyName);
```

Note: the *return type* (`object`) means that many types will need to be boxed. Since you mention you are doing this for filtering: if possible, try to avoid this box by creating instead a `Func<object,bool>` that does any comparisons etc internally without boxing.

Comment: This works perfect! :)
How would you add the Expression Equal and another parameter to compare to?
I'm Guessing a Func<object,object,bool> (obj, value, result) ?

Comment: @Nautious well, then you'd be boxing the input instead each time, so probably no gain; I was thinking more `Expression.Equal(..., Expression.Constant(expectedValue))`

Comment: After playing around a little with this, i still get an exception on the return type, just like you mentioned in your Note. 
Apparently it don't mind returning strings and URI's , but TimeSpan, Int32 and Double throws ArgumentException, so the body definitely needs to boxed. :/
Body part will be the following: `var body = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(Expression.Convert(arg, type), name), typeof(object);`

Comment: @Nautious I *thought* it did boxing automatically, but it would seem not :(